# Why do Python dunder methods override NumPy universal-function-overrides in custom array element?

Tags: arrays, numpy, numpy-ufunc

I am trying to make a Python object (called a Stroke) that can be used as elements in NumPy arrays and operated on by NumPy universal functions.

I wish to do the following comparison operation:

```py
x = Stroke(...)
y = Stroke(...)
z = Stroke(...)

arr = np.array([x, y, z], dtype=object)

output = np.greater(arr, 5)

# OR

output = np.greater(arr, Stroke(...))
```

For my case, I would also like to custom define how the universal function, `np.greater`, works on arrays of Stroke's. I tried making this custom definition using the `__numpy_ufunc__` method as described [here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.dispatch.html).

Unfortunately, when calling `np.greater`, the `Stroke.__gt__` dunder method is used to evaluate `np.greater` rather than my custom defined function. How can I force NumPy to use of the custom defined `np.greater` function instead of the dunder method without removing the dunder method?

A relevant snippet of the Stroke code is seen below:

```py
from polare._numpy_ufunc_overrides import HANDLED_FUNCTIONS
import numpy as np


class Stroke:

    def __gt__(self, other):

        return self._binary_operation(np.greater, other)
    
    ...


    def __array_ufunc__(self, ufunc, method, *inputs, **kwargs):

        if method == '__call__':

            if ufunc in HANDLED_FUNCTIONS:
                func = HANDLED_FUNCTIONS[ufunc]
                return self._handle_functions(func, *inputs)
            else:
                # Handle the ufunc in a different way.

        else:

            return NotImplemented
```

where the `HANDLED_FUNCTIONS` dictionary is populated with the following code:

```py
import numpy as np


HANDLED_FUNCTIONS = {}


def implements(np_function):
    def decorator(func):
        HANDLED_FUNCTIONS[np_function] = func
        return func
    return decorator


@implements(np.greater)
def greater(a: np.ndarray, b: np.ndarray) -> list:
    ...
```

Comment: Needs a [mcve].  What do you mean by "used in arrays"?  `np.array([Stroke(), Stroke()]` or something else?

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, I have made edits.

Comment: So `arr` is `object` dtype?  Normally `np.greater(arr, 5)` would be the equivalent of `np.array([ x>5 for x in arr])`.  I don't know what whether your added definitions change what's happening.  `arr>5` would do the same.  Most operators work with objects; functions like `np.exp(arr)` raise an error, saying that `<element> does not have a exp method`..

Comment: The problem that arises, is when the `Stroke.__gt__` method is used it casts the elements of `arr` to `bool` types; I want to keep the elements as `Stroke` objects but modified internally. I left out the code but I have defined general handling of ufunc operations so I do not get the error you noted.